# Hibernate JOIN with possible NULL parent

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables:

Campaign:

| CAMPAIGNID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Players:

| PLAYERID | CAMPAIGNID | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | JOHN |
| 2 | 1 | JOHN |
| 3 | NULL | JOHN |

with Hibernate mapping OneToMany - one Campaign has many Players with cases where Player does no belong to any Campaign.

I would like to fetch list of Players for NAME=JOHN grouped by Campaign. My current working solution is that I fetch data from Players table and group them in Java code with check if Player.campaign is NULL then I create some dummy Campaign data in response.

I would prefer some other solution than going through all returned Player data and mapping to appropriate Campaign manually.

I tried with native query using RIGHT JOIN and I get all results (2 Campaigns in the list) but can not access the second one since its NULL.

Is there a way to populate second Campaign (NULL) with some dummy data so I can access list of Players inside second Campaign?

Comment: You should be able to use an _outer_ join in your query to load players and their associated campaigns if there are any. What exactly does "grouped by campaign" mean? Are you loading all players and just want to group them? Or do you want a count of players per campaign including the "null" campaign (players that are not part of a campaign yet)? Can you provide examples of the results you want to get? Can you also share the relevant portions of your entities, i.e. how they are mapped etc.?

Comment: @Thomas Desired result would be list of Campaign entities containing list of Players inside each of them. With access to Player list that are not connected to any campaign. I get desired number of Campaigns using following query: "select c from Campaign c right join Player p on c.campaignId = p.campaignId where p.name = 'JOHN';
Result is List<Campaign> campaigns .....; has two elements and I am able to access the first one and see players inside - campaigns.get(0).players .... but when I try to access the players for second Campaign (campaigns.get(1).players) I get NPE since Campaign is NULL.

Comment: Sure, when loading campaigns you should not load the "null" campaign. Instead, you might want to rethink your approach and either do 2 queries - 1) campaigns with players and 2) players that are not part of a campaign (yet) - or introduce that special dummy campaign into your code. If you can't/don't want to do any of this you might need to keep the grouping code in Java which shouldn't be too complex anyway (I'd say less than 10 lines probably) - that can be easier to maintain than moving all that complexity to a repository or query.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, grouping code is very simple but I am a bit concerned about the amount of Player results and performance of this manual grouping. Everything is done in one for loop using HashMap for a holder of grouped data. Not sure how fast this will work with hundreds of Player results. Two queries would complicate things more since I need a specific order based on other Player properties, and then would have to loop results again to order them. I was just wondering when asking this question, if there is a way to tell Hibernate to let me access that list of players where its parent is NULL.

Comment: @Thomas The other solution would be to create dummy Campaign in Database in the moment of inserting Player and connect Player with that dummy Campaign so there is never a Player without Campaign stored.

Comment: Exactly, you could introduce that dummy campaign into DB and assign new players to it. Maybe even add a constraint that this campaign must be the only one a player is assigned to - if it is assigned. When a player joins a real campaign the dummy is disconnected and the constraint would enforce this. However, looping over a hundreds or even thousands of players in a loop isn't that costly in the first place. There will be other performance bottlenecks already (e.g. loading that data) - so I wouldn't bother with the loop unless it proves to be a bottleneck.